# Finding P value

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I have these observations $(2,3.2,3.8,2.5,3.3,2.8,3.0,3.4)$ from $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and i want to calculate the $P$-value testing $H_0: \mu =3.2$ against $H_1 \neq 3.2$ with $\sigma = 0.6$

should i calculate $P r(X > 3.3) $ and $Pr( X < 3)$ and add these togheter ?

I tried it using that  $X = Y\sigma + \mu  \sim N(0,1)$ but the answer don't seem to be right according to the solution which is $P = 0.347$

Anyone can tell me what Iam doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that $\sigma = 0.6$, and under the assumption that the null hypothesis $H_0 : \mu = 3.2$ is true, what is the probability of having observed a result as extreme as the sample mean $\bar X = 3$?  The test statistic is $$Z = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} = \frac{3 - 3.2}{(0.6)/\sqrt{8}} = -0.942809,$$ where $Z \sim {\rm Normal}(0,1)$ is a standard normal random variable.  Thus we wish to calculate $\Pr[|Z| > 0.942809]$, which we look up in a table:  we get $2(0.172889) = 0.345779$, which is the $p$-value of the test.  Note that my answer is more precise than the one you gave.  This is because I used a computer to obtain the appropriate percentile of the standard normal distribution, rather than a table.

Comment: in terms of $\bar{X}$ your saying that $Pr(\bar{X} \leq 3)$ + $Pr(\bar{X} \geq 3.4)$. When saying extreme then you mean deviates more than $\vert 0.2 \vert$ from 3.2 . @heropup

Comment: In a manner of speaking, yes.  But with respect to hypothesis testing, we usually speak of the distribution of the test statistic itself, rather than of the sampling distribution, because the test statistic is generally independent of scale and location.  It's easier and clearer to look up the probability of being in the critical region.