# P-value hypthesis test(my bad - found same question in math stack)

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

**textbook exercise**

How can I calculate P-value at a test of $$H_0: u=3.2$$ against $$H_1: u \neq 3.2$$ if  we have the observations $2.0$, $3.2$, $3.8$, $2.5$, $3.3$, $2.8$, $3.0$ and $3.4$ which is a sample from $N(u,o^2$), there $u$ and $o^2$ are espected value respectively variance.

I have calculated the confidence interval to $$I_u=(2.58,3.42)$$
rejection region to
$$C=(|T|\geq1.96)$$ where $$T=\frac{u^*-u_0}{\frac{o}{n^{1/2}}}$$
$u^*$=$m$=mean value of the observations.

EDIT:

[Finding P value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695677/finding-p-value?rq=1)

Comment: Wow, literally the same question with exactly the same observations. Is this a textbook question? If so, it would be worth mentioning in the post.

Comment: Yes it is @Rahul