# what does extreme really mean in P-value method

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, descriptive-statistics

if $P:=P_{H_0}$(To get an equally extreme outcomes that the observed), what does "equally extreme outcomes mean then? For an example in this [situation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695677/finding-p-value). How does he get that " When saying extreme then you mean deviates more than |0.2| from 3.2 "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a normal distribution with mean $3.2$ and standard deviation $0.6$, it would be very surprising if the average of your observations turned out to be $8$. It would be less surprising if the average turned out to be $4$, so we would say that $8$ is more extreme than $4$. But $-10$ is more extreme than either because it is $13.2$ away from the mean rather than $0.8$ or $4.8$.

In general for a normal distribution, the further away from the mean, the more extreme (surprising) the result.

We want the p-value to be the probability of getting a result *at least* as extreme as that actually observed. Anything $\geq 3.4$ or $\leq 3.0$ is at least as far away from the expected mean (and hence at least as surprising/extreme) under the null hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks. But why not $\geq 3.3$ or $\leq 3.0$? @Raoul

Comment: @bonnyalma: A normal distribution is symmetric (http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Empirical_Rule.PNG), so being $\geq 3.4=3.2+0.2$ would be exactly as surprising as being $\leq 3.0=3.2-0.2$ (think of the areas in the picture). The further you go from the mean, the more extreme the result. If you set your significance level at 5%, you are saying that anything more than (about) two standard deviations from the mean is sufficiently surprising that it probably wasn't a fluke.

Comment: We definitely want the $3.0$ (because it's the sample mean), so we calculate the $3.4$ by going the same distance from the mean but in the other direction. If the sample mean had been $2.1$ instead then you would want to consider $\leq 2.1$ and $\geq 4.3$.

Comment: This is a two-tailed test. I don't know exactly what you've covered, but sometimes you might want to do a one-tailed test instead. The idea is basically the same, but you would only need to worry about the $\leq 3.0$ case (the "tail" on the left of the picture).

Comment: thanks alot. everything became clearer now :) @Raoul